# XAMPP MySQL starts then stops

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

So I've tried a lot of things and can't get my SQL to work (Apache is working)

Here is the error log. All it does is show green in the control panel then just stops.

```
2018-04-14 14:42:34 37c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-04-14 14:42:34 892 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 0 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 1835107 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-04-14 14:42:34 37c  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 892 in file fsp0fsp.cc line 1880
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
180414 14:42:34 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787129 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!?propagate_equal_fields@Item@@UAEPAV1@PAVTHD@@ABVContext@Value_source@@PAVCOND_EQUAL@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?propagate_equal_fields@Item@@UAEPAV1@PAVTHD@@ABVContext@Value_source@@PAVCOND_EQUAL@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?get_key@MDL_ticket@@QBEPAVMDL_key@@XZ()
mysqld.exe!?propagate_equal_fields@Item@@UAEPAV1@PAVTHD@@ABVContext@Value_source@@PAVCOND_EQUAL@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?get_select_id@Explain_basic_join@@UAEHXZ()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Here is the other code

```
2:42:33 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
2:42:34 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
2:42:36 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: What did you try so far, which version did you use and how did you install MySQL?

Comment: I installed it via the auto installer with Xampp. (I have WAMPSERVER aswell) Ive tried changing ports, deleting various things, running XAMPP as an admin, etc

Comment: The logs are showing corruption in the InnoDB tablespace, try to add `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in my.ini file.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the record.   I'm getting this exact same error on several different machines.  All seem to be virus free.   I would say a serious bug has escaped debugging and development.  It may require an earlier install of Xampp or checking the MD5 to make sue there isn't a compromise of the distribution

Comment: Which version of Xampp is virus free ?